# break text (new lines) for every value

Tags: angular

How can I break text into my textarea in Angular 2?

I got compontent which shows some details.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Details</div>
    <br>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="" class="form-horizontal" *ngIf=alias>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mail: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <p class="form-control">{{alias.name + '(at)' + alias.domain}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="recipients" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Recipients: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <textarea class="form-control" row="4" col="50"> {{ alias.recipients }} <br></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info" (click)="goBack()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried add `<br>` in `textarea` but doesn't works.
I want to get something like this:
Output:

> alias.recipient1
>
> alias.recipient2
>
> alias.recipient3

Instead alias.recipient1, alias.recipient2, alias.recipient3 (Now i have this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app logic (controller or whatever you are using), you must separate them (assuming they are currently separated by comma-space):

`alias.recipients = alias.recipients.split(', ').join('\n\n');`